# At what point do immigrants acquire the right to due process

Tags: us-constitution, immigration

I am asking this because president Trump is calling for sending immigrants who approach the border from Mexico to be sent back without due process. I strongly suspect that it is illegal but a lot of googling and watching cable TV has not pinned down a possible loophole.

While it is completely uncontroversial that any person on US soil has the right to due process, I have not seen anything that gives these rights to people who approach the border but are prevented from crossing it. Specifically, what allows them to be granted admission, activating their right to due process.

The fourteenth amendment does explicitly protect “...life, liberty, or property, without due process...within its jurisdiction...”.

questions:
 - does interaction with a US border guard, even if one isn’t yet in the country, count as “within its(USA) jurisdiction”?
- does refusal of admittance violate any of life, liberty or property?
- is the proposal of the president legal?

I had expected that this question would be answered here alreadynbut I was unable to find anything.

Comment: Keep in mind that this isn't an all or nothing matter. You can have due process rights re criminal prosecutions brought by the US, and due process rights re property or paternity that US authorities influence, even if you don't at a given moment have a due process right in your immigration status or right to enter the US. There is case law on when a due process right in immigration status attaches which I'll provide an answer on if I get a chance. But, the fact that you have due process rights with respect to one thing does not answer the question as to other things.

Comment: According to guest27.., a border guard denying entry would be a legal means to exclude immigrants, as long as he did not taken the immigrant into custody. That would seem to validate the President’s proposal, especially if his “wall” were built and was effective.

Comment: I have found a reference on this - the Madison lecture from June 2013 in the NYU law review(easily googleable). One relevant sentence: “...the supreme court has held that exclusion at the border is free from due process constraints...”. Seems to indicate that the proposal is legal although there is some mention of problems with the 8th amendment.I still have trouble believing this so I am still looking.

Comment: The rule is basically that you can be refused when crossing the border. But, this excludes people who have certain kinds of visas, people who claim U.S. citizenship and people who claim asylum.

Comment: @ohwilleke we are talking about people without visas or citzenship but they will generally be claiming asylum. I assume that the latter is not mentioned in the constitution but that it is covered by subsequent precedent. On what basis were these cases judged. Do you have a reference?

Comment: @abbyyorker For clarity, is the question attempting to establish that individuals whom are within the Jurisdiction (by any means) of the United States do not have the right to due process?

Comment: @guest: I want to know whether the government can stop people at points of entry, before admission, and simply turn them around such that they never even cross the border. I realize that illegal immigrants who have entered the country have due process rights. Is that also true for people who have not managed to cross the border?

Comment: @abbyyorker Of course the government can stop people at any point, the government of the U.S. possesses the overwhelming materials to do so. The government need not "turn them around". The government needs only to stop forward progress into the Land where the U.S. asserts Jurisdiction. Of course, that would be contrary to existing laws relevant to "asylum", but answers your question.

Comment: Lets try a view that may seem less controversial: Landing at an international air terminal (say JFK), despite being on a US runway, a person is NOT technically on US soil until they have gone thru immigration inspection. So, while the building of a port of entry may be actually on US soil, technically it is in a no-man's land. OTHO, crossing the border at other than a POE, is actually standing on US soil, both practically and technically.  The consequence is obvious, the most effective route to obtaining due process  is to cross improperly.

Comment: @BobE that's not correct.  The people *are* on US soil.  I've even seen an episode of a reality TV show in which someone got in trouble for illegal entry at a port of entry in Texas or California because he had done something that prevented him from applying for admission, but the government maintained that he entered the US as soon as he crossed the border.  They haven't been "admitted" under immigration law, but they have *entered,* and they are subject to US jurisdiction. There's no no-man's land; if there were, people could commit crimes there with impunity.

Comment: no-man's land is probaby not the best choice of words (my bad). I seem to recall that recently the FBI, wanting to seize a Russian's cell phone etc pursuant to a search warrant  had to wait until that Russian had cleared immigration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that I now have enough information to answer my question thanks to the discussion here. I change the wording somewhat due to new info in the discussion.

Do new immigrants presenting themselves at entry points have a right to due process (regarding the civil matter of immigration application, similar to the due process rights of deportables)?
No, as they are not yet legally admitted to the USA although they may be detained on US soil. Importantly, the courts look very strongly to congress to decide on immigration policies. The law is clearly explained in:

https://scholarship.law.cornell.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2724&context=clr

Can the immigration force refuse them admission, returning them to their home country or to Mexico?
Yes, after the an officer has decided that their asylum claim has no merit. At present, they do have an option of presenting their case to an impartial judge but the DOJ is right now revoking that option, which was never a guaranteed right. If the judges are removed, it’ll be hard to see the process as anything but a sham, where admission becomes harder and harder according to the directives from above.

https://www.axios.com/ag-sessions-vacates-precedent-of-asylum-0a52e9a4-44a4-4087-a198-77c5ab92a37c.html

Does international law provide any requirement of due process or admission criteria? 
I do not think so. It seems very difficult to do even in principle as countries have diverse principles and politics. I could not find any binding laws. After some more search, I found: “Under both U.S. law and international treaties that came after the Holocaust, border officials must allow people who say they’re afraid to return home to submit their claims in the asylum process”. I am still looking at what the treaties say.

Comment: "They are not yet on US soil" is only correct if they are at a pre-clearance port of entry.  Ports of entry at land borders are physically in the US.  The no-man's land analysis is incorrect.  The lack of due process rights flows from other factors.

Comment: @phoog: You may be right about the US soil - I got my statement from https://www.nytimes.com/2018/06/25/us/immigration-border-nogales-mexico.html?rref=collection%2Fissuecollection%2Ftodays-new-york-times&action=click&contentCollection=todayspaper&region=rank&module=package&version=highlights&contentPlacement=2&pgtype=collection

Comment: The wording in the very first sentence was where I got “no man’s land”. A clearer treatment indicates that their documentation is checked physically outside the US but the asylum interview is held within the country. Prior to a successful interview, they have not officially entered the country and are indeed labeled as inadmissables http://www.sandiegouniontribune.com/news/immigration/sd-me-asylum-process-20180427-story.html

Comment: I do maintain that their lack of rights is based on their not having been admitted. They are physically in the country but not legally. This is stated on page 824 of the reference I provided "Aliens who have neither been inspected nor admitted and are not entitled to be in the country are inadmissible". And, further in the same paragraph: "...initially arriving aliens...fall in the inadmissible category because they stand at the border waiting to be inspected and admitted." This is despite the fact that they are physically in the country.

Comment: The first sentence of *what* is where you got "no-man's land"? I don't see it. Anyway the fact of having not yet been admitted does limit their rights for the purpose of immigration law, but it would not, for example, allow the government to imprison them for the.commission of a (non-immigration) crime without a trial.  In other words, they are on US soil and they do have certain rights, even if they do not include a right to judicial review of a decision to refuse admission.

Comment: @phoog. “...and on a spit of floor separating Mexico from Arizona...” from the nyt article. But I accept that they are on US soil and do have rights under criminal prosecution(the latter of which I was not addressing). My question, unclearly stated, was centered on the question of whether they would receive civil due process similar to that given to “deportables”, who have been inspected and admitted. Modifying the answer as we go.

Comment: That article was datelined Nogales.  It's not clear to me from the article whether the people being profiled are between the border and the immigration desks or actually still on the Mexican side of the border.  I get the impression that the reporter doesn't understand fully.  You may be interested in Wong Wing v. US and Yick Wo v. Hopkins or other aspects of [How does the US constitution apply to aliens?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/238/333) These nineteenth-century cases established the rights of aliens in the US in the context of a lack of rights for aliens arriving at the border.

Comment: The NYT statement is confusing and likely misleading. The other article, from the San Diego Tribune is much clearer. San Diego applicants are held in Otay Mesa Detention Center which is in the US.

Answer (score 4):

An individual obtains due process rights upon entering into the United States. For a recent write-up on this question, see [this piece at Reason](https://reason.com/volokh/2018/06/25/a-quick-due-process-lesson-for-the-presi).

The people Trump is talking about generally aren't being denied admission at an established, legal border crossing; they're coming across wherever they can get through, and only being discovered by federal agents thereafter. Because they're already in the United States, they have due process rights.

As for cross-border interactions with ICE or CBP, the extent of due process protections is still an open question. [SCOTUS took it up last year](http://www.scotusblog.com/case-files/cases/hernandez-v-mesa/), but it kicked the case back to a lower court rather than deciding it.

Comment: I read the reason piece, but it applies to immigrants on US soil and I do not see any controversy there. They get due process. The tweet they quote does imply that, so fair enough. However, the President has a later tweet: “Hiring manythousands of judges, and going through a long and complicated legal process, is not the way to go - will always be disfunctional. People must simply be stopped at the Border and told they cannot come into the U.S. illegally. Children brought back to their country......”, which implies no entry...

Comment: I have never understood the administration’s infatuation with the wall but it might serve to funnel immigrants to bona fide entry points, at which they can be turned away without entering the US. Seems unlikely to work as a 3000 mile wall can be gamed, but maybe this is a clue to what they are thinking.

Comment: I've always understood that these (and other) rights are applicable once a person *is admitted to the US* - which is not the same thing as *entering the US*.

Comment: @brhans that is incorrect.  A person who is suspected of unlawful entry has a due process right to have that suspicion tried before a judge.  If the person did in fact enter unlawfully, then the person was never admitted to the US, but still has a due process right to require the government to establish that fact in court.

Comment: @phoog - yeah, that makes more sense.

Answer (score -3):

> At what point do immigrants acquire the right to due process

When an individual is taken into the custody of the United States.

Comment: _"This Constitution, and the laws of the United States which shall be made in pursuance thereof; and all treaties made, or which shall be made, under the authority of the United States, shall be the supreme law of the land; and the judges in every state shall be bound thereby, anything in the Constitution or laws of any State to the contrary notwithstanding."_ Constitution of the United States, Article VI

Comment: This doesn't sound accurate. For example, if an immigrant owned land in the US the government can't take it via eminent domain without due process, nobody ever is taken into custody regarding eminent domain cases, due process is still needed. You might be right about dealing with illegal immigration at the border, but as it stands your answer is too general to be correct.

Comment: @Matt The Constitution is the Supreme Law of the Land. Agents of the United States derive the source of their enforcement power from the Constitution of the United States. From the immigrants' perspective the matter is simple: the custody took place in the Jurisdiction of Land, not Admiralty-Maritime Jurisdiction. The 14th Amendment of the Constitution of the United States applies, period. From the perspective of the Government, their actions ignore the Constitution of the United States. As long as the immigrant stands on solely the Supreme Law of the Land argument, they declare Jurisdiction

Comment: Okay... Your answer to the question is still overly general. You don't have to be taken into custody of the United States or an agent thereof in order for you to have the right to due process for some cases, such as my eminent domain example above.

Comment: @Matt If your argument is that the Constitution of the United States does not apply to either the agent of the state nor the individual whom the agent of the state takes into custody by force, then, yes, the Due Process Clause of the Constitution does not apply, in fact, the Constitution itself does not apply, because that is your argument.

Comment: @Matt The answer is very specific. For a reason. Imminent domain is not the case at bar. The individual must stand on the Supreme Law of the Land. Compel the Government to assert that the Constitution does not apply.

Comment: I don't know why you think I'm arguing that the constitution doesn't apply to the agent of the state or the individuals, my statement is based on precisely the opposite. Your answer is not specific at all, its incredibly general. To make it specific you need to add some words limiting your statement's scope. As it stands you are literally saying immigrants acquire the right to due process when they are taken into the custody of the United States. However, there are plenty of immigrants that have never been taken into the custody of the United States that have due process rights.

Comment: What? `The individual must stand on the Supreme Law of the Land` and `Compel the Government to assert that the Constitution does not apply` Those statements are nonsensical.

Comment: Those statements are nonsensical regardless of how much experience I have litigating in federal court. You might want to read them again if you think they make sense. Anyway, you are getting wayyyy off track here. All I'm saying is that your answer is incredibly general and because of that is clearly wrong.

Comment: @Matt As a matter of law, the state assumes custody of the individual when they take them into custody, restraining their Fundamental Liberty Interest guaranteed by the 14th Amendment. From there the individual can assert Jurisdiction in a competent court of law using statutes, that is laws passed by Congress, or invoke Jurisdiction under the organic Law of the Land, the Constitution of the Untied States. Arguments solely over assertion of jurisdiction can takes years, before even reaching the merits of the case.

Comment: How does the 14th Amendment even come into play in an interaction with a federal agent?

Comment: @bdb484 Have you read the last comment before posting your comment?  This answer does not address "interaction", as the individual can simply remain silent and have no "interaction" with the agent. Once custody of the individual occurs The Fundamental Liberty Interest  is applicable to the individual once the agent takes the individuals into custody, and the Due Process Clause is applicable to both the individual and the states, both of which are guaranteed by the 14th Amendment to the Constitution of the United States.

Comment: guest271314: I think @bdb484 was trying to point out that in federal matters due process is guaranteed by the fifth amendment, not the 14th ("nor be deprived of life, liberty, or property, without due process of law").  The 14th amendment establishes the right of due process with respect to state law ("nor shall *any State* deprive any person of life, liberty, or property, without due process of law", emphasis added).

Comment: @phoog The 14th Amendment guarantees more than that. The 14th Amendment guarantees not only procedural due process, but also [substantive due process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substantive_due_process); and establishes an individuals' Fundamental Liberty Interest, which is also applicable as to the federal government. Few actually challenge the substance of laws, or invoke the Constitution itself as Jurisdiction in a federal Court; that does not mean those options do not exist; individuals, lawyers tend to rely on statute. The 5th Amendment can also be invoked to establish Jurisdiction.

Comment: @phoog  If the Government does not take individuals into their custody there is no controversy. The Government could simply state: we are not accepting any more people, we are filled to the brim, and repeal asylum laws. Instead, the Government fumbles and flounders with incoherent policies and practices which clearly involve the Fundamental Liberty Interest of individuals. The Government could further simply do: immediate transfer of the person outside of the Jurisdiction of the United States. However the U.S. has existing asylum laws, and the Constitution; i.e., the U.S. is a nation of laws.

Comment: @guest271314 the US has asylum laws because of international obligations.  It would not be such a simple matter to repeal them.  I also do not understand your assertion that the government could transfer people outside the jurisdiction of the US.  How could that be done without due process (unless the constitution were first amended to permit such an action)?

Comment: @phoog You make the same argument that is made in the answer. Those individuals whom are taken into custody by the U.S. and the agents of the U.S. which take individuals into custody are governed first and foremost by the Supreme Law of the Land.  Not sure what answer is expected other than the individuals have the substantive right to Due Process and the Government must  comport with those Due Process protections guaranteed by the Constitution of the United States; whether the argument is that Due Process (substantive and procedural) occurs upon Land of the U.S. or upon custody by the U.S.?